# How to get the exact path of the currently active file in VS Code while creating an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, filepath, vscode-extensions

I am creating a VSCode extension.

I want to get the exact path of the file that is currently open in the editor!

How do i get it!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri.fsPath
```

if you want the posix version on Windows platforms (you have to deal with the `:`)

```
vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri.path
```